# FATAL EXCEPTION: receiver not registered?

Tags: java, android

im new here and new to java, working on my first project, which, was all going great until I added a new button to an activity and the app wouldnt start! (on a tablet)

I reverted any changes back to the way they were but im still having this problem, this code WAS working fine before this and i cant for the life of me work out why!

my application has two activity's, the launch activity is a bluetooth setup page (or it will be when its done) this has buttons to turn on/off bluetooth, search for devices, list paired devices and a button to switch to the second activity which is a screen with some buttons on to perform some action which isnt finished yet and a back button to return to the first activity.

My problem occurs when i change to the second activity from the first, and i get "unfortunately bluetoothtest has stopped".

heres the logcat error:

```
07-07 16:01:38.757: D/AndroidRuntime(3595): Shutting down VM
07-07 16:01:38.757: W/dalvikvm(3595): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception        (group=0x40d89930)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy     activity {com.javacodegeeks.android.bluetoothtest/sjtech.rompa.wifi.Bluetoothsetup}:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered:   sjtech.rompa.wifi.Bluetoothsetup$1@413a0858
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3586)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3605)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:158)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: sjtech.rompa.wifi.Bluetoothsetup$1@413a0858
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:662)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1707)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:452)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at sjtech.rompa.wifi.Bluetoothsetup.onDestroy(Bluetoothsetup.java:233)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5495)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1127)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3573)
07-07 16:01:38.757: E/AndroidRuntime(3595):     ... 11 more
07-07 16:01:39.976: I/Process(3595): Sending signal. PID: 3595 SIG: 9
```

Im sorry if this isnt formatted correctly, this is my first time.

this is the .java for the first page where i think the error occurs:

```
package sjtech.rompa.wifi;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import com.javacodegeeks.android.bluetoothtest.R;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Bluetoothsetup extends Activity {

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
//private static final String TAG = null;
private Button onBtn;
private Button offBtn;
private Button listBtn;
private Button findBtn;
public Button wifiscreen;
private TextView text;
public BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter;
private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
private ListView myListView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> BTArrayAdapter;
private ProgressBar progressBar1;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.bluetoothsetup);


  // take an instance of BluetoothAdapter - Bluetooth radio
  myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

  //if the device doesnt have bluetooth disable all buttons 
  if(myBluetoothAdapter == null) {
      onBtn.setEnabled(false);
      offBtn.setEnabled(false);
      listBtn.setEnabled(false);
      findBtn.setEnabled(false);

      //set 'status' to show:
      text.setText("Status: not supported");

      //show toast with comment:
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your device does not support Bluetooth",
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      //if device has bluetooth set on click listener's for buttons
  } else {

      text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
      onBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOn);
      onBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            on(v);
        }
      });

      offBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOff);
      offBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            off(v);
        }
      });

      listBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.paired);
      listBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            list(v);
        }
      });

      findBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search);
      findBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            find(v);

        }
      });


      wifiscreen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wifiscreen);
      wifiscreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Button wifiscreen changes from bluetooth to wifi page
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Wifi.class);
            startActivity(intent);   

            }
      });


      myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    //  setForeground( Color.RED );   

      // create the arrayAdapter that contains the BTDevices, and set it to the ListView
      BTArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
      myListView.setAdapter(BTArrayAdapter);
        }

    }

            //if bluetooth is turned on request android bluetooth start request
     public void on(View view){
     if (!myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
     Intent turnOnIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
     startActivityForResult(turnOnIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

     //show message for bluetooth start
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth turned on" ,
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     //show message for bluetooth already on
  }
  else{
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth is already on",
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
    // set 'status' to bluetooth status
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
       if(myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
           text.setText("Status: Enabled");
       } else {   
           text.setText("Status: Disabled");
        }
   }
   }

         public void list(View view){
  // get paired devices
        pairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

  // put it's one to the adapter
  for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
      BTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName()+ "\n" + device.getAddress());
  // display toast message
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Show Paired Devices",
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }

   final BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
             // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
         BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
             // add the name and the MAC address of the object to the arrayAdapter
             BTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
             BTArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};

               public void find(View view) {
         if (myBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {

          //if the button is pressed when it discovers, cancel the discovery
          myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

   }
   else {
    BTArrayAdapter.clear();
    myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));

}    

  }

          // show 'status' that bluetooth is disabled
         public void off(View view){
      myBluetoothAdapter.disable();
      text.setText("Status: Disconnected");
      //show toast that bluetooth is disabled
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth turned off",
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

            @Override
            protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);  
   }

}
```

am i right in thinking its related to the unregisterReciever or the closing of the first page of the app when starting the second activity? I noticed that when changing to the second activity is the point where the app closes, however it appears to close, then reverts to the first activity instead of closing completely.

As i mentioned earlier, this exact code worked fine and then this error appeared from nowhere, i was only adding a button another activity, which i removed just on the offchance but to no avail.

If you need other code to help me i will gladly provide it!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you unregistering `unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);` in `onStop() / onPause()` as well?. Where are you registering the receiver?

Comment: show us the entire code... Where are you calling `find()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try register your receiver in onResume(), is it possible that you register in onCreate()?

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

For example, do you have something like this in onCreate()?

```
private void setUpReciever(){
   reciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               //your code
  }

  IntentFilter intFilt = new IntentFilter("yourKey");
  registerReceiver(reciever, intFilt);
}
```